# Decoding data to Struct fails

Tags: swift, struct, collections, codable

Currently, I have a custom struct that conforms to Codable

```
struct Language: Codable {
    var isoCode: String
    var name: String
    var translations: [String: String]
}
```

And, then proceeding with encoding it successfully works

```
let lang = Language(isoCode: "en", name: "English", translation: ["greetings": "morning"])
let langEncoded = try? lang.encode()
```

The problem arises when I try to decode data into Language struct

```
let lang = Language.decode(from: langEncoded)
```

Producing an error message: ***Error message: Ambiguous use of 'decode(with: from:)'***

Comment: `let langEncoded = try? lang.encode()` no it doesn't work. You are not encoding anything there. You need to do `let langEncoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(lang)`

Comment: To decode `let langDecoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Language.self, from: langEncoded)`. I wonder why don't you read de documentation or search a bit before posting another question on SO about Codable protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do as follow.

## Code:

```
 let lang = try JSONDecoder().decode(Language.self,from: langEncoded)
```